# Nginx configuration for a wordpress blog in a subfolder of Symfony root

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, nginx, nginx-config

I am running a Symfony 4 application in the main root and need to have a Wordpress blog to be available at /blog

This is how I would like the apps to be served:

```
website.com -> Symfony App (working)
website.com/blog -> Wordpress (returning 404)
```

With my current configuration, the Symfony app is working but the blog is returning a 404.

```
server {
    listen              *:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         www.website.com;

    client_max_body_size 1m;
    charset utf-8;

    set $host_path "/var/www/website.com";
    set $symfony_bootstrap "index.php";

    root $host_path/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /blog {
        root /var/www/blog;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        root   $host_path/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$symfony_bootstrap$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        root  $host_path/public;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # add caching to built resources
    location /build {
       alias $host_path/public/build/;
       access_log off;
       expires max;
    }

    server_tokens off;
    sendfile off;
}
```

How can I have nginx to handle Wordpress site under the /blog location?

Comment: I think you need to dete the line 10 i think. `root $host_path/public;`

Comment: @Ahmedbhs just tried now, but getting the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put wordpress files in `/public/blog` directory, where `/public` is the public directory of symfony and configure nginx like that:

```
location /blog {
    root      /var/www/website.com/public;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
Here is full example config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com
  root /var/www/website.com/public;

  location /blog {
    root      /var/www/website.com/public;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;  
    internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/website.com_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/website.com_access.log;
}
```

Like i said in the comments, make sure you are using correct php socket in your `fastcgi_pass` directives.

Comment: That's giving now a 502 bad gateway for website.com/blog

Comment: @Martin Make sue you use php5 socket. I pasted php7 one, because i'm using php7. My answer is checked - i'm using it in my production setup and it is working. Or even better check which one you are using, because in your `blog` location you have `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` and in your / location you are using `fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;` - that's 2 different things

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer with full config example.